# Navigate nested has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have nested has_many associations

Project has many Parts
Part has many Tasks
Task has many jobs

Is there a better way to get all the jobs associated to a project than

```
project.parts.each do |p|
  p.tasks.each do |t|
    t.jobs.each do |j|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might add an `has_many` association with the `through` option, while you define a `#jobs` method in your `Project` model.

For instance :

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
  has_many :tasks, through: :parts

  def jobs
    jobs = []
    tasks.each {|t| jobs << t.jobs }
    jobs.flatten
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I will probably try something like that. I actually have 4 models nested into each other (not three) but the idea is the same.